# Python throws an error when importing pyautogui module, exit code 3

Tags: python

Every time i import pyautogui in Thonny (Windows 7, 64 bit), the program refuses to execute and will display the following text: "Process ended with exit code 3."

Here's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvep0.png)

I tried to find an explanation of that error code but couldn't find any. Did anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Welcome @Amar Delic! You tried write some code using pyautogui to check if that error persist?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.